# How to make arrow key skip list item with class disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown list(`<ul>`)  where I disabled clicking some of the options with a class

```
.disbaled {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

the problem is these items can still be selected with the arrow keys scrolling down or up in the list. How can I make the arrow keys skip the disbaled options and go to the next option that is not disabled?

Comment: Please provide the code of your list

Answer (score 0):

you can use hasClass in jquery

```
if ($("ul li").hasClass("disabled")) {
   ...
}
```

or in css

```
ul li:has("disabled"){
  ...
}
```

Comment: `has` is in working draft, it's far from being implemented anywhere